# How to link JcheckBoxes to JtextFields when they are being dynamically generated?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, jcheckbox

i want my app to create jcheckboxes from an input that always changes.
I want to create a jtextfield near every checkbox, that will be set enabled, only when his checkbox is pressed.

I managed to create this code:

```
 //Create checkboxes with textfileds
    for (int i = 0; i < activeProjects.length; i++) {
        projectPanels[i] = new JCheckBox(activeProjects[i]);
        projectPanels[i].setSelected(false);
        projectPanels[i].setComponentOrientation   (ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        projectPanels[i].setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        projectPanels[i].addItemListener(this);

        projectStorageNum[i] = new JTextField("");
//          projectStorageNum[i].setEnabled(false);
        projectStorageNum[i].setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        projectStorageNum[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        projectStorageNum[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        projectStorageNum[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        projectStorageNum[i].setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        tmppnl = new JPanel();
        tmppnl.add(projectStorageNum[i]);
        tmppnl.add(projectPanels[i]);

        checkBoxPanel.add(tmppnl);

    }
```

and this is my state change listener:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
Object source = e.getItemSelectable();
JCheckBox myBox= (JCheckBox)source;
String bName = myBox.getText();

if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
{
// enable matching text field.
// add bName to projects list.
}
    else
    {
     //disable matching textfield
     // remove bName from list
    }
```

when I access the checkboxes in a dynamic way I don't have access to the second array of textfields.
is there any way to link them , or any other idea ?

thanks

Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is use the setName and getName methods of Component to save the index of the JCheckBox.

```
projectPanels[i].setName(Integer.toString(i));
```

Then, in your state change listener.

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(e.getName());
```

This gives you the index of the JTextField.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of solution I'm looking for, but I get the error massage : The method getName() is undefined for the type ItemEvent

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map` (Hashmap) the checkbox would be the key and the textField the value returned when you do the key loopup.